# Is it possible to get item selected after browser reload from dropdown list when it is populated based on another select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to get selected an option from select list when it is based on another select list after browser reload. well, i know what i wrote above is little bit confusing. I'm trying to explain as much as i can. I've two dropdown. 
First dropdown list :

```
      <select id = "select-class" name="class_id"  class="form-control"
             required>
                <option> শ্রেণি নির্বাচন</option>
            <?php foreach ($all_class as $cls) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $cls->class_id ; ?>">
            <?php echo $cls->name; ?></option>
            <?php }?>
    </select>
```

This select list is pretty much clear. It gives me a list of class names and their value.

Second dropdown List:

```
      <select id = "select-section" name="section_id" class="form-control"> 
           <option> প্রথমে শ্রেণি নির্বাচন করুন </option>
      </select>
```

This select list is populated after changing the first one by this approach :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("#select-class").change(function () {
    var class_id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url();?>frontend/ajax_class/"+ class_id,
        data: {class_id: class_id},
        type: "post",
        success: function(msg){

            if(msg){
                $("#select-section").fadeIn();


                $("#select-section").html("<option>select a section</option>"+msg);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#select-section").fadeOut();

            }
        }

        });
    });
```

and when the 2nd dropdown list is changed it loads all the related things like this pic. 
            [image]
by this approach :

```
        $(function(){



            $("#opt_subjcts").hide();   

            $("#select-section").change(function () {

                    var class_id = $('select[name=class_id]').val();

                var section_id = $(this).val();

                var result1;
                var result2;
                $.when(
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: "<?php echo site_url();?>frontend/ajax_subjects/"+ class_id + "/" + section_id ,
                        type: "post",      
                        success: function(returnhtml){     
                                result1 = returnhtml;                  
                        }           
                    }), 
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: "<?php echo site_url();?>frontend/ajax_opt_subjects/"+ class_id + "/" + section_id ,
                        type: "post",      
                        success: function(returnhtml){     
                                result2 = returnhtml;                  
                        }           
                    })

                ).done(function() {
                    $("#opt_subjcts").hide();
                    if(class_id >= 6){
                    $("#opt_subjcts").show();
                    }
                    $("#subjct").html(result1);
                    $("#rec_sub").html(result2);
                    $("#opt_sub").html(result2);
                });


            });
        });

        </script>
```

Pls notice that i've to select both of dropdown list one after another to get my those stuff. Now i want to get those thing when the browser is loaded. I mean i will provide class_id and section_id from the backend and those will be appeared based the on class_id and section_id the as i will provide . Any Idea pls.

Comment: In order to retain values on page reload you can use Localstorage- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

> Use `trigger` to initiate `change` event forcefully.

Try this:

```js
 $(function() {
       $("#select-class").change(function() {
         var class_id = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
           url: "<?php echo site_url();?>frontend/ajax_class/" + class_id,
           data: {
             class_id: class_id
           },
           type: "post",
           success: function(msg) {

             if (msg) {
               $("#select-section").fadeIn();


               $("#select-section").html("<option>select a section</option>" + msg);
             } else {
               $("#select-section").fadeOut();

             }
           }

         }).change(); //OR .trigger('change')
       });
```